# Error when updating datas in the database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to solve this little problem.
I have a form that allows to modify datas to a db, but when I click on the submit button(even if it changes the values), it shows an error:
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("name") to generate a URL for route "update_page".
500 Internal Server Error - MissingMandatoryParametersException

Can anybody help me?

This is my controller:

```
class updateElementController extends Controller
{       
public function updateAction($name)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $ingrediente = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyCrudBundle:Elements')
    ->findOneByName($name);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $elementsmod = new Elements();

    $formupdate = $this->createFormBuilder($elementsmod)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('quantity', 'text')
        ->add('Change element', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $formupdate->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formupdate->isValid()) {
    $newval = $formupdate->getData();

    // change "entity" / object values we want to edit
    $namevalue= $newval->getName();
    $quantityvalue= $newval->getQuantity();
    $element->setName($namevalue);
    $element->setQuantity($quantityvalue);

    // call to flush that entity manager from which we create $item
    $em->flush();

    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('update_page'));
    }

    return $this->render('MyCrudBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $formupdate->createView(),
    )); 
}
}
```

And my route:

```
update_page:
pattern:  /updatePage/{name}
defaults: { _controller: MyCrudBundle:updateElement:update }
```

(if you need other parts of code, just tell me, I'm a beginner and most certainly it's horribly written)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two options:

1. If the `name` is not mandatory in your routing you can change your routing as below

   `update_page:
      pattern:  /updatePage/{name}
      defaults: { _controller: MyCrudBundle:updateElement:update, name: null }`
2. If the `name` is mandatory for the generated url you need to pass the `name` as the pattern param

   `if ($formupdate->isValid()) {
      $newval = $formupdate->getData();
      $namevalue= $newval->getName();
      $quantityvalue= $newval->getQuantity();
      $element->setName($namevalue);
      $element->setQuantity($quantityvalue);
      $em->flush();
      return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('update_page', array('name' => $name)));
   }`

*base on your query selection you have in your controller the `$name` is mandatory and I suggest to try the second one*

Comment: requires 15 reputation...at the moment I can't vote up, but I will :D